# How to decode Ascii code in a Character in PHP

Tags: php, html, ascii, decode, urldecode

I got the string in this format

solr/?key=color&facet=Blue%26keyword%3Dwoo

---

However, I want to get it in this format

solr/?key=color&facet=Blue&keyword=woo

Answer (score 1):

Try [`urldecode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php):

```
$url = urldecode("solr/?key=color&facet=Blue%26keyword%3Dwoo");
// = solr/?key=color&facet=Blue&keyword=woo
```